# Using `process.emit('info')` as opposed to `process.emit('warning')`

Tags: node.js

It appears to be common practice for libraries to use

```
const err = new Error('some warning');
process.emit('warning', err);
```

*so that the user-land library can log the error or handle the error, their way.*

However, I am wondering, is there a convention for handling info level messages instead of warning level messages.

Might it be

```
process.emit('message',msg) // no that's reserved for IPC messages
```

what about

```
process.emit('info', msg);
```

anybody know?

Comment: Maybe exploring different "node.js logging" options would be useful. There are several different options and there is no One True Way. The "emit warnings" approach (with some specifically defined interaction rules with Node, and [limited to this defined event](https://medium.com/@jasnell/introducing-process-warnings-in-node-v6-3096700537ee)) is probably best left for things that 'one might expect to see on a stderr if it was a console app'. These are generally things that could turn the world sidewise, as opposed to informational bits of data.

Comment: do you think it's a good question?

Comment: I don't think it's a "bad question".